# Validation for int(input()) python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def is_digit(x):
    if type(x) == int:

        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    shape_opt = input('Enter input >> ')
    while not is_digit(shape_opt):
        shape_opt = input('Enter input >> ')
        
    else:
        print('it work')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So when the user input a value that is not an integer, the system will repeat the input(). Else, it does something else. But it won't work, may I know why?

Comment: `input` _always_ returns a string. `type("1")` is still `str`. Also you should generally use `isinstance(x, y)` rather than `type(x) is y`, and rather than `if condition: return True else: return False` you can just `return condition`.

Answer (score 1):

Check this. Input always returns a string. So `isdigit()` is better to use here. It returns True if all characters in a string are digits and False otherwise.

`return x.isdigit()` will evaluate to True/False accordingly, which will be returned

```
def is_digit(x):
    return x.isdigit()
    
def main():
    shape_opt = input('Enter input >> ')
    while not is_digit(shape_opt):
        shape_opt = input('Enter input >> ')
        
    else:
        print('it work')    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to test if an string is an int is to do this:

```
def is_digit(x):
    try:
        int(x)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `try except` when trying to convert to `int`.
if it fails to convert the data inside `int()` then throw the exception inside except which in your case with makes the loop continue.

```
def is_digit(x):
    try:
        int(x)
        return True
    except:
        return False


def main():
    
    shape_opt = input('Enter input >> ')
    
    while not is_digit(shape_opt):
        
        shape_opt = input('Enter input >> ')
    else:
        print('it work')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```